# Help figuring out to make a file path string

Tags: c, unix, filesystems

For the current project, I have to create directories using the mkdir function.  In order to do that, I'm having trouble adapting an example `pwd` code to produce a string containing the file path to the current directory.

I modified the [original example code](http://www.cs.usm.maine.edu/~boothe/cos350/courseExamples/l12/pwd1.c) to take in both the node and a string, and as it recursively traverses up the file tree, each step is written to the string.  Then when the base case is hit, the string is returned to the original function.

Sorry for the long code snippet

```
//modified from book, need to get entire file path to create new directories
char *printpathto( ino_t this_inode, char* name)
{
  ino_t my_inode ;

  if ( get_inode("..") == this_inode ) //root points to self
    return name;

  chdir( ".." );              /* up one dir */

  // find this dirs actual name
  if (inum_to_name(this_inode,name,BUFSIZ)) 
    { // 1st: print parent dirs recursively 
      my_inode = get_inode( "." );      
      printpathto( my_inode, name);
    }   

  return name;
}

int inum_to_name(ino_t inode_to_find, char *namebuf, int buflen)
{
  DIR       *dir_ptr;       /* the directory */
  struct dirent *direntp;       /* each entry    */

  dir_ptr = opendir( "." );
  if ( dir_ptr == NULL ){
    perror( "." );
    exit(1);
  }

  //  search directory for a file with specified inum
  while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL )
    if ( direntp->d_ino == inode_to_find )
      {
    strncpy( namebuf, direntp->d_name, buflen);
    namebuf[buflen-1] = '\0';   /* just in case */
    closedir( dir_ptr );
    return 1;
  }

  strcpy(namebuf, "???");   // couldn't find it
  return 0;
}

ino_t get_inode( char *fname )
{
  struct stat info;

  if ( stat( fname , &info ) == -1 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot stat ");
    perror(fname);
    exit(1);
  }

  return info.st_ino;
}
```

When I run it through the debugger, the current directory is displayed in the string, but the next call is when the SIGABORT occurs and the backtrace is printed.

First, I had to modify the original code to return a string rather than print it to stdout, but I'm not sure why this backtrace dump is occuring.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with `getcwd()`?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        printf("Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
        }
    else {
        printf("getcwd() error %i",errno);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That did it.  Thing is, `getcwd()` is nonexistent in my Unix text, and it hasn't been covered in class either.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jason: If this is [homework] the whole point might be to implement an equivalent to *getcwd(3)* yourself (e.g. to properly manage your memory while making recursive calls and to gain a better understanding of how directories relate to inodes). You may not get credit if you just use *getcwd(3)*.